# Is priority queue a non-linear data structure?

Tags: priority-queue

If yes then why priority queue is a non-linear data structure? Does non-linear data sturctures are bad in performance as compared to linear ones? If yes then why? Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Linear Data Structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures#Linear_data_structures) are lists and arrays. [Priority Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) is an abstract data structure (abstract means it can be implemented in terms of other data structures in multiple ways) usually implemented in terms of a heap. For performance measurement, usually the asymptotic cost of operations is used. For example, how much time does `N` insertion operations take?

Sorry this is an incomplete answer. A complete answer is beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: What makes a Data Structure linear or non-linear in the first place? What data structures are good for searching and sorting?

Comment: Did you try searching on google? What do you think? It is irritating to try and answer a bunch of questions asked point-blank without a knowledge of how much effort the asker has put to try to find an answer himself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Priority queue is a non linear data structure which is implemented using a linear data structure (queue)